# Find out the current version of a crate from a lint?

Tags: rust, internals, rust-crates

I'm working on an extended deprecation lint that can decide if something *already is* or *will be* deprecated. There is one problem left, though: Crates do not appear to have version information. I know that I can get the current Crate's version using some environment variable that cargo will set, but that's not enough to distinguish deprecated parts of dependencies.

I can at least get the current crate path via `ctx.sess.local_crate_source_file` (as in fhahn's [current PR](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy/pull/544/files).

So barring getting the filepath and finding and parsing `Cargo.lock` manually (which I consider to be fragile and hacky), is there a way to get the dependencies' version numbers and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Use `#[deprecated]` instead, see [Rust lang rfc 1270](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1270-deprecation.md) for documentation. This is stable since Rust 1.9. Then the compiler does the job of the lint you want to create.

A way to instead implement what you asked for without touching the compiler or using a compiler feature is to include the version in the crate its public API and use that from your lint.

Comment: I wrote that RFC. And sorry, in that case finding and parsing Cargo.lock is the better option. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Why do you think that is also better than getting the version from the API of the crate whose deprecations you want to lint about?

Comment: I'm a bit late, but could you not put the version information into the crate at compile-time, e.g. with an `include!` macro and/or a build script?